# ¿Cómo eliminar valores de una columna?

Tags: r

Tengo un data frame que tiene los siguiente el siguiente contenido:

```
 SFC_info:     
       DP=5;AD=0,5;VDB=0.292572;SGB=-0.590765
       DP=7;AD=0,7;VDB=0.372161;SGB=-0.636426
       INDEL;IDV=16;IMF=0.888889;DP=18;AD=10,8;VDB=0.060
       DP=5;AD=0,5;VDB=0.292572;SGB=-0.590765
       DP=7;AD=0,7;VDB=0.372161;SGB=-0.636426
       INDEL;IDV=7;IMF=1;DP=7;AD=0,7;VDB=0.536793;SGB=-0.5
```

En algunas filas de esta única columna tengo estos valores

```
      INDEL;IDV=16;IMF=0.888889;
      INDEL;IDV=7;IMF=1;
```

Me gustaría saber como elimiarnos de la columna y tener esta columna

```
      DP=5;AD=0,5;VDB=0.292572;SGB=-0.590765
      DP=7;AD=0,7;VDB=0.372161;SGB=-0.636426
      DP=18;AD=10,8;VDB=0.060
      DP=5;AD=0,5;VDB=0.292572;SGB=-0.590765
      DP=7;AD=0,7;VDB=0.372161;SGB=-0.636426
      DP=7;AD=0,7;VDB=0.536793;SGB=-0.5
```

¿Alguien sabría decirme como hacerlo?
Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Esto por ejemplo: `DP=5;AD=0,5;VDB=0.292572;SGB=-0.590765` es una sola columna? ¿Lo que buscarías es eliminar las claves `INDEL`, `IDV` y `IMF`?

Comment: Es un ejemplo en pequeño, aparece varios valores diferentes y busco que en todas las filas que aparece IND, IDV=; IMF; se eliminen automáticamente para posteriormente separar la DP y la AD automáticamente de cada fila

Comment: respondiendo mejor a tu pregunta, si, cada fila es independiente, no tienen ningun patrón que se repite salvo que son tres factores que es INDEL, IDV y IMF y que son los tres primeros en algunas filas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurre que puedes usar expresiones regulares para buscar los tres patrones y reemplazarlos por nada o más bien `''` mediante la función base `gsub()`. El patrón sería algo así:

```
INDEL;|              # Buscamo "INDEL;" o
IDV=\\d+\\.?\\d*;|   # IDV= y un número con o sin decimales más ; o bien 
IMF=\\d+\\.?\\d*;    # IMF= y un número con o sin decimales más ;
```

La idea conceptual sería:

```
df <- data.frame(valor= c('DP=5;AD=0,5;VDB=0.292572;SGB=-0.590765',
                          'DP=7;AD=0,7;VDB=0.372161;SGB=-0.636426',
                          'INDEL;IDV=16;IMF=0.888889;DP=18;AD=10,8;VDB=0.060',
                          'DP=5;AD=0,5;VDB=0.292572;SGB=-0.590765',
                          'DP=7;AD=0,7;VDB=0.372161;SGB=-0.636426',
                          'DP=5;AD=0,5;VDB=0.292572;SGB=-0.590765',
                          'INDEL;IDV=7;IMF=1;DP=7;AD=0,7;VDB=0.536793;SGB=-0.5'),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE
                 )

# Los datos originales
print(df, right=FALSE)

  valor                                              
1 DP=5;AD=0,5;VDB=0.292572;SGB=-0.590765             
2 DP=7;AD=0,7;VDB=0.372161;SGB=-0.636426             
3 INDEL;IDV=16;IMF=0.888889;DP=18;AD=10,8;VDB=0.060  
4 DP=5;AD=0,5;VDB=0.292572;SGB=-0.590765             
5 DP=7;AD=0,7;VDB=0.372161;SGB=-0.636426             
6 DP=5;AD=0,5;VDB=0.292572;SGB=-0.590765             
7 INDEL;IDV=7;IMF=1;DP=7;AD=0,7;VDB=0.536793;SGB=-0.5

rexp <- 'INDEL;|IDV=\\d+\\.?\\d*;|IMF=\\d+\\.?\\d*;'

df$valor <- gsub(rexp, 'X', df$valor)

# Los datos finales    
print(df, right=FALSE)
  valor                                 
1 DP=5;AD=0,5;VDB=0.292572;SGB=-0.590765
2 DP=7;AD=0,7;VDB=0.372161;SGB=-0.636426
3 XXXDP=18;AD=10,8;VDB=0.060            
4 DP=5;AD=0,5;VDB=0.292572;SGB=-0.590765
5 DP=7;AD=0,7;VDB=0.372161;SGB=-0.636426
6 DP=5;AD=0,5;VDB=0.292572;SGB=-0.590765
7 XXXDP=7;AD=0,7;VDB=0.536793;SGB=-0.5
```

Comment: PERFECTO!, funciona, una vez más, muchas gracias Patricio